# MongoTemplate.find() returning a list of integers results in NoSuchMethodException (no default constructor)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am attempting to query a list of integers from a mongo collection using spring-data-mongo but it throws an exception when generating the results because Integer has no default constructor:

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("acceptsEmails").is(true));
query.fields().include("userId");
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Integer.class);
```

The problem is that the following exception is generated because it appears that it attempts to instantiate Integer using a default constructor (which obviously does not exist).

```
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.lang.Integer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>()
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.<init>(BeanWrapper.java:105) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.create(BeanWrapper.java:73) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:239) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:151) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:73) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1693) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1444) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1259) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1248) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:471) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.lang.Integer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:107) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.<init>(BeanWrapper.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Any idea on a workaround to get a list of integers returned? This is a very large list of integers so I'd prefer not to use an intermediate format such as String which I then have to iterate over and convert to Integers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can register a custom converter from `DbObject` (the data type you're actually getting from the driver) to `Integer`.

Probably something like this will do the trick:

```
public class UserIdReadConverter implements Converter<DBObject, Integer> {
    public Integer convert(DBObject source) {
        return Integer.parseInt((String) source.get("userId"));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you still need to convert the result values to Integer. You can see in the docs if this solution could be a useful workaround.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters

Bye
Carlo